# Principal component analysis in matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I have a training set with the size of (`size(X_Training)=122 x 125937`).

- `122` is the number of features
- and `125937` is the sample size.

From my little understanding, PCA is useful when you want to reduce the dimension of the features. Meaning, I should reduce 122 to a smaller number.

But when I use in matlab:

```
X_new = pca(X_Training)
```

I get a matrix of size `125973x121`, I am really confused, because this not only changes the features but also the sample size? This is a big problem for me, because I still have the target vector `Y_Training` that I want to use for my neural network.

Any help? Did I badly interpret the results? I only want to reduce the number of features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the documentation of the PCA function is useful: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html.  It mentions that the **rows are the samples** while the **columns are the features**.  This means you need to transpose your matrix first.

Secondly, you need to specify the number of dimensions to reduce to *a priori*.  The PCA function does not do that for you automatically.  Therefore, in addition to extracting the principal coefficients for each component, you also need to extract the scores as well.  Once you have this, you simply subset into the scores and perform the reprojection into the reduced space.

In other words:

```
n_components = 10; % Change to however you see fit.
[coeff, score] = pca(X_training.');
X_reduce = score(:, 1:n_components);
```

`X_reduce` will be the dimensionality reduced feature set with the total number of columns being the total number of reduced features.  Also notice that the number of training examples does not change as we expect.  If you want to make sure that the number of features are along the rows instead of the columns after we reduce the number of features, transpose this output matrix as well before you proceed.

Finally, if you want to automatically determine the number of features to reduce to, one method to do so is to calculate the variance explained of each feature, then accumulate the values from the first feature up to the point where we exceed some threshold.  Usually 95% is used.

Therefore, you need to provide additional output variables to capture these:

```
[coeff, score, latent, tsquared, explained, mu] = pca(X_training.');
```

I'll let you go through the documentation to understand the other variables, but the one you're looking at is the `explained` variable.  What you should do is find the point where the total variance explained exceeds 95%:

```
[~,n_components] = max(cumsum(explained) >= 95);
```

Finally, if you want to perform a reconstruction and see how well the reconstruction into the original feature space performs from the reduced feature, you need to perform a reprojection into the original space:

```
X_reconstruct = bsxfun(@plus, score(:, 1:n_components) * coeff(:, 1:n_components).', mu);
```

`mu` are the means of each feature as a row vector. Therefore you need add this vector across all examples, so broadcasting is required and that's why `bsxfun` is used. If you're using MATLAB R2018b, this is now implicitly done when you use the addition operation.

```
X_reconstruct = score(:, 1:n_components) * coeff(:, 1:n_components).' + mu;
```

Comment: Dear @rayryeng, I know it's usually frustrating to see people asking questions without doing enough research, but due many circumstances I had no choice. Thank you for your understanding, thank you for you effort to detail and explain to me and thank you for your time !!

Comment: @U.User you're very welcome. Sometimes I find it easier if someone tells you straight up on what you should do, instead of consulting the documentation. If I can be honest, the documentation on the PCA function in MATLAB is quite verbose and can definitely get lost in translation. It's why I ultimately decided to elaborate on how to use the function. Good luck and let me know if you need any more help!

Comment: Thank you.Yes actually,When I use the commands you typed to automatically determine the number of features to reduce to.It prints an orange message which says that some columns are linearly dependent,and that the system will use the first 8 components to compute TSQUARED.And the new size of X_reduce is  125973x2 (pretty low actually).But I when apply  mapstd() on my X_Training in order to do feature scaling and normalization,I do get the same orange error but it says that it will use the first 117 columns this time, and the final output is size(X_reduce)= 125973 x 89. Should I apply mapstd()?

Comment: @U.User it's a problem with your training matrix.... But when it computes the PCA, it calculates the covariance matrix which inherently does the feature scaling for you so I'm rather confused. But yes, it seems mapstd is more reliable.

Comment: lol sorry, yes I think that too. During the preprocessing phase, my X_training had 3 categorical features in which one had a lot of values, so when I did one-hot encoding to the categorical features I moved from 42 to 122 features. So, my matrix is full of 0s ans 1s, that's why I thought of using mapstd().